# Find a basis of a 3rd order polynomial that contains the basis of a kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For clarity this is a coursework question so I'm not looking for an answer and more of a nudge in the general direction.

The question starts

The map $\theta :\Bbb{R}_3 [t] \rightarrow  \Bbb{R}^3\ $ is given by $at^3+bt^2+ct+d\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}2a-4c\\0\\6c-3a\end{bmatrix}$

The first part of the question involve finding a basis for the kernel of $\theta$ which I found to be the set $B = \left\{(1),(t^2),(t^3+t/2)\right\}$

The next part then asks me to find a basis of $\Bbb{R}_3[t]$ that contains $B$

I am completely stuck as to what to do here and would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_3[t]$ is a four dimensional vector space so you need four independent vectors to make a basis. With kernel's basis already providing you 3 independent vectors, you now have to add one more vector to the list which should be independent from the ones already in the kernel's basis. Hint: look for something that is not in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the question and editing, I think i understand now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

*Theorem: any linearly independent family of vectors can be completed into a basis by picking up vectors from an existing basis*.

So take a basis of $V=\mathbb R_3[t]$... there is a famous one! And pick up one of the vector of this famous basis to transform the linearly independent family $B$ of vectors that generates $\ker \theta$ into a basis of $V$.

Additional hint... in your pick up process, some vectors are better than the others.

Comment: So, as I understand, the basis of V is $\left\{(1),(x),(x^2),(x^3)\right\}$ but as I want it to contain $B = \left\{(1),(t^2),(t^3+t/2)\right\}$ i can simply choose one of the elements $(t^3),(t)$, include it in $B$ and this will form the basis i require?

Comment: @RhysSpiteri your choices are good but for sake of clarity (that this is not an arbitrary choice) you need to make sure that either of your choices does not live in the kernel.

Comment: @AnuragA I'm not understanding this bit sorry, do you mean something such as $(t^2−t)$ one that involves multiple orders of t not already in the kernel.

Comment: @RhysSpiteri to check if $t^2-t$ is in the kernel or not, all you need to check is if $\theta(t^2-t)=(0,0,0)$ or not. In this case it isn't because it maps to $(4,0,-6)$. Thus we can include $t^2-t$ as a basis member to extend the basis of the kernel to that of $\mathbb{R}_3[t]$

Comment: @AnuragA thank you very much for all your help